# How can I change the onClick function of a button saved in a useRef object in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm learning state and hooks in React. I'm doing an exercise to deal cards from a deck using the [deckofcardsAPI](http://deckofcardsapi.com/), not the most important code on the interwebs, but it does bring about a question. In fact, it's not even part of the exercise, I just really want to do it.

I have a button that is stored in a `useRef` object. I really would like the `onClick` function to change, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

// auto dealer, 1 card/s turned on or off

function CardTable2() {

    const [src, setSrc] = useState('');
    const deckId = useRef();
    const remaining = useRef(52);
    const isDealing = useRef(false);
    const timerId = useRef();
    const button = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        timerId.current = setInterval(() => {
            if (isDealing.current) {
                dealCard();
            };
        }, 1000);

        async function createDeck() {
            const res = await axios.get(`http://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1`);
            deckId.current = res.data.deck_id;
        };
        createDeck();

        return () => { clearInterval(timerId.current) }
    }, []);

    async function dealCard() {
        if (remaining.current === 0) {
            alert('You are out of cards');
            isDealing.current = false;
            button.current.innerText = "Shuffle deck";
            button.current.onClick = shuffleDeck;
            return;
        }
        console.log(button);
        const res = await axios.get(`http://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId.current}/draw/?count=1`);
        remaining.current = res.data.remaining;
        setSrc(res.data.cards[0].image);
    };

    async function shuffleDeck() {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId.current}/shuffle/`);
        setSrc('');
        button.current.innerText = "Start dealing cards";
        button.current.onClick = toggleDealing;
    }

    function toggleDealing() {
        isDealing.current = !isDealing.current;
        button.current.innerText = "Start dealing cards";
    };


    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={toggleDealing} ref={button}>{isDealing.current ? "Stop dealing cards" : "Start dealing cards"}</button>
            <div>
                <img className="CardBox" src={src} alt="a card" />
            </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default CardTable2;
```

I've tried setting the `button.current.onClick` to the function, as seen above, but it doesn't actually seem to have an effect. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is the return is just putting back {toggleDealing} every time.

Why not get rid of the ref and just have a generic function handle both cases?

```
const [buttonMode, setButtonMode] = useState("shuffle")

function handleClick() {
    if (buttonMode === "deal") {
        deal()
    } else if (buttonMode === "shuffle") {
        shuffle()
    } 
}
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this should be a ref `const isDealing = useRef(false);`

Changing a ref doesn't cause react to re-render. It's a like a mutable box that won't trigger the re-render. But `isDealing` does have consequences on what gets drawn no? 

Therefore, I think it should be useState (calling the set function will trigger the re-render)

Comment: Again, I'm still learning, so to me useRef also functions well as a persistent variable, regardless of re-renders. What else would I use (trying to avoid a global variable, because that is *not* the react way).

Comment: Basically, the way to think about it is: if this piece of state has rendering implications (think something changes visually on the screen), then it needs to be useState. We use useRef often when we just want to read some value out of an input and store it there so we can reference it later with the current property (like when we are going to call an api )

Comment: Changing it to state causes a new render everytime it's toggled. So when I click to start the dealing, it re-renders, and therefore halts in the process. That may be a cause of something else related (another piece of my shitty code), but changing it to state interferes with the timer (the interval).

Comment: Nope, just had to include `isDealing` in the array passed in the second position to the useEffect.

Comment: No worries, good luck :) Also remember that wading through "shitty code" is the path to the truth. Also, if you want your useEffect to trigger when a state changes, then -- yes -- add it to the useEffect dependencies array. Sometimes we only want the useEffect to trigger when the state is -- say -- false. Then what we do is add a little "bouncer" logic at the top of the useEffect that prematurely returns (i.e.: if (!isSomething) return)